# Jest: how to mock console when it is used by a third-party-library?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, jestjs

I am trying to mock console.warn/error but I can't. I use a third-party-library which calls console.warn inside it. I need to test was it called or wasn't. In my test case I was trying to stub console.warn but it didn't help. After that I was trying to mock console manually it didn't work out either.

```
console.warn = jest.fn();
testSchema('/app/components/Users/UserItem/UserItemContainer.js');
expect(console.warn).toBeCalled();
```

didn't work

```
console.warn = jest.fn();
testSchema('/app/components/Users/UserItem/UserItemContainer.js');
console.warn('error');
expect(console.warn).toBeCalled();
```

did work.

But I still see `console.warn node_modules/babel-relay-plugin/lib/getBabelRelayPlugin.js:138` in the terminal.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You have to use `global` to access objects in the global context

```
global.console = {warn: jest.fn()}
expect(console.warn).toBeCalled()
```

or use `jest.spyOn` added in `19.0.0`

```
jest.spyOn(global.console, 'warn')
```

Comment: Are you sure?  Still does not work.                                                                              `global.console = {
    warn: jest.fn(),
    error: jest.fn(),
  };
  testSchema('/app/components/Users/UserItem/UserItemContainer.js');
  expect(global.console.warn).toBeCalled();`

Comment: I use it to test out logging functionality, its `expect(console.warn).toBeCalled()` to test the calling.

Comment: Yes guys it works. But one thing is that you have to require the lib after you declare global.console. I did it wrong. I required my lib and after that declared global. Thank you.

Comment: Also it doesn't work when you use ES6 import feature. It only works with require.

Comment: Interesting how this is not documented anywhere on Jest's website. I am searching and can't find anything explaining this.

Comment: with typescript: _error TS2322: Type '{ warn: Mock<{}>; }' is not assignable to type 'Console'._

Comment: it works with *console.warn = jest.fn();* _global.console = {warn: jest.fn()}_

Comment: Ive updated the answer, `spyOn` should also work in typescript

Comment: just so that everyone's aware. `global.console = {...}` will _suppress_ the error while `jest.spyOn(...)` will not.  You decide if you want errors suppressed or not in your tests.

Comment: I prefer `jest.spyOn(...)` because it is easier to clean up and I'm using TypeScript but also wanted to suppress errors in the output as @a11smiles mentions. So I used `jest.spyOn(global.console, "warn").mockImplementation(() => {})` which prevents the spy calling through to the underlying `console.warn`

Comment: @djskinner That's the best solution, as you can mock the particular method without replacing the whole thing. You might want to make that an answer...

Comment: when testing `checkPropTypes` and using `spyOn`, all tests after a failed case are also failed, but assigning `global.console` with a new `fn()` in each test worked for me, thanks!

Comment: how can i mock the logger.error and check different test cases , i have posted a question any help appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250372/logger-implementation-using-winston-morgan-and-winston-daily-rotate-file

Answer (score 161):

Use `jest.spyOn()` and `mockRestore()`.

```
const consoleWarnMock = jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation();
...
consoleWarnMock.mockRestore();
```

The accepted answer does not restore the original `console.warn()` and will "compromise" the other tests inside the same file (if `console.warn()` is used inside the other tests or the code being tested).

FYI if you use `console.warn = jest.fn()` in a test file, it won't affect other test files (e.g console.warn will be back to its original value in the other test files).

Advice: you can call `consoleWarnMock.mockRestore()` inside `afterEach()`/`afterAll()` to be sure that even if a test crashes, it won't compromise the other tests from the same file (e.g ensures the tests inside the same file are fully isolated).

Full example:

```
const consoleWarnMock = jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation();
console.warn('message1'); // Won't be displayed (mocked)
console.warn('message2'); // Won't be displayed (mocked)
expect(console.warn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
expect(consoleWarnMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // Another syntax
expect(console.warn).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('message2');
expect(consoleWarnMock).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('message2'); // Another syntax
expect(consoleWarnMock.mock.calls).toEqual([['message1'], ['message2']]);
expect(console.warn.mock.calls).toEqual([['message1'], ['message2']]);
consoleWarnMock.mockRestore(); // IMPORTANT
//console.warn.mockRestore(); // Another syntax

console.warn('message3'); // Will be displayed (not mocked anymore)
expect(consoleWarnMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0); // Not counting anymore
expect(consoleWarnMock.mock.calls).toEqual([]);
//expect(console.warn.mock.calls).toEqual([]); // Crash
```

You cannot write

```
console.warn = jest.fn().mockImplementation();
... 
console.warn.mockRestore();
```

because it won't restore the original `console.warn()`.

/!\ With `mockImplementationOnce()` you will still need to call `consoleWarnMock.mockRestore()`:

```
// /!\
const consoleWarnMock = jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementationOnce(() => {});
console.warn('message1'); // Won't be displayed (mocked)
expect(console.warn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(consoleWarnMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // Another syntax
expect(console.warn).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('message1');
expect(consoleWarnMock).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('message1'); // Another syntax
expect(consoleWarnMock.mock.calls).toEqual([['message1']]);
expect(console.warn.mock.calls).toEqual([['message1']]);

console.warn('message2'); // Will be displayed (not mocked anymore)
// /!\
expect(console.warn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // BAD => still counting
expect(consoleWarnMock.mock.calls).toEqual([['message1'], ['message2']]);
expect(console.warn.mock.calls).toEqual([['message1'], ['message2']]);

consoleWarnMock.mockRestore(); // IMPORTANT
//console.warn.mockRestore(); // Another syntax
console.warn('message3'); // Will be displayed (not mocked anymore)
expect(consoleWarnMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0); // Not counting anymore
expect(consoleWarnMock.mock.calls).toEqual([]);
//expect(console.warn.mock.calls).toEqual([]); // Crash
```

You can also write:

```
const assert = console.assert;
console.assert = jest.fn();
...
console.assert = assert;
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me; jest 25.5.4. It just doesn't mock the console method. The number of calls is zero and the original method(`console.error` for me) still gets called.

Comment: @cst1992 hey , did you find any other way to test it , if so please let us know that would be great , i am also stuck with this issue .

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand No luck yet :(

Comment: @cst1992 oh no :( me too , could not find yet

Comment: I was going to suggest spying on `globalThis.console` instead of just `console`, which worked for me, but now I find that plain `console` is also working for me (Jest 26.6) so maybe I'm just lucky? :( Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

You could try the following, test and pleae make sure to have `clearMocks` to `true` in your jest config file.

```
test('it should console warn a message', ()=>{
    jest.spyOn(global.console, 'warn').mockImplementation();

    console.warn('my error');
    expect(console.warn).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    expect(console.warn).toBeCalledWith('my error');
})
```

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    clearMocks: true,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the logs from appearing in your test execution first create a `consoleMocks` file and add it to the jest configuration

```
setupFiles: ['./test/consoleMock.js'],
```

In the `consoleMocks` file add the following:

```js
global.console = {
  ...global.console,
  log: jest.fn(),
  warn: jest.fn(),
}
```