# Can't mock console.error using Jest + React

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

How does one mock console.error?

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Button from '../Button';

describe('<Button>', () => {
  it('should fail proptype validation if the autoWidthGroupId contains anything but letters and numbers', () => {
    const myMock = jest.fn();
    console.error = new myMock();
    shallow(<Button autoWidthGroupId={'bad id'}>Hello</Button>);
    expect(myMock).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Gives me the following error

```
● <Button> › should fail proptype validation if the autoWidthGroupId contains anything but letters and numbers

TypeError: console.error is not a function

  at printWarning (node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:36:17)
  at warning (node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:60:22)
  at checkReactTypeSpec (node_modules/react/lib/checkReactTypeSpec.js:80:49)
  at validatePropTypes (node_modules/react/lib/ReactElementValidator.js:151:5)
  at Object.ReactElementValidator.createElement (node_modules/react/lib/ReactElementValidator.js:194:5)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Button/__tests__/Button.test.jsx:53:60)
```

Environment info:

- react 15.2.1
- jest 17.0.3
- enzyme 2.4.1

**UPDATE**

This is a duplicate question, I guess.  Here is how I solved the issue using the other Stackoverflow post

```
  it('should fail proptype validation if the autoWidthGroupId contains anything but letters and numbers', () => {
    const myMock = jest.fn();
    global.console = { error: myMock };
    shallow(<Button autoWidthGroupId={'bad id'}>Hello</Button>);
    expect(myMock).toBeCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223963/jest-how-to-mock-console-when-it-is-used-by-a-third-party-library)?

Comment: That seems to do the trick.  I guess it's a duplicate question. Sorry folks.

Comment: Glad it worked :)