# JavaScript - mocking console in Jest / mock "was not called"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to mock `console.info` which I know will be called when an imported function runs. The function consists entirely of a single `fetch` which, when not running in production, reports the request and response using `console.info`.

At the question [Jest. How to mock console when it is used by a third-party-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223963/jest-how-to-mock-console-when-it-is-used-by-a-third-party-library), the top-rated answer suggests overwriting `global.console`, so I'm using [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to try that out:

```js
import * as ourModule from "../src/ourModule";

test("Thing", () => {
    // Tested function requires this. Including it here in case it's causing
    // something quirky that readers of this question may know about
    global.fetch = require("jest-fetch-mock");

    const mockInfo = jest.spyOn(global.console, "info").mockImplementation(
        () => { console.error("mockInfo") }
    );

    ourModule.functionBeingTested("test");
    expect(mockInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

As expected, the output contains an instance of "mockInfo". However, then testing that with `toHaveBeenCalled()` fails.

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

  40 |
  41 |     ourModule.functionBeingTested("test");
> 42 |     expect(mockInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();
     |                      ^
  43 | 

  at Object.toHaveBeenCalled (__tests__/basic.test.js:42:22)

console.error __tests__/basic.test.js:38
  mockInfo
```

I've tried moving the `spyOn` to before the module is loaded, as suggested in one of the comments on the answer, with no difference in result. What am I missing here?

Here's the function in question:

```js
function functionBeingTested(value) {
    const fetchData = {
        something: value
    };

    fetch("https://example.com/api", {
        method: "POST",
        mode:   "cors",
        body:   JSON.stringify(fetchData),
    })
        .then( response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                if (MODE != "production") {
                    console.info(fetchData);
                    console.info(response);
                }
            } else {
                console.error(`${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
            }
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: What is the third party library function that you are calling?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors: I'm not, that's from the other question.

Comment: Can you show what `ourModule.functionBeingTested` does?

Comment: It fetches a URL - I've added that to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

`console.info` is called in a Promise callback which hasn't executed by the time `ourModule.functionBeingTested` returns and the `expect` runs.

### Solution

Make sure the Promise callback that calls `console.info` has run before running the `expect`.

The easiest way to do that is to return the `Promise` from `ourModule.functionBeingTested`:

```js
function functionBeingTested(value) {
  const fetchData = {
    something: value
  };

  return fetch("https://example.com/api", {  // return the Promise
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    body: JSON.stringify(fetchData),
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        if (MODE != "production") {
          console.info(fetchData);
          console.info(response);
        }
      } else {
        console.error(`${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

...and wait for it to resolve before asserting:

```js
test("Thing", async () => {  // use an async test function...
  // Tested function requires this. Including it here in case it's causing
  // something quirky that readers of this question may know about
  global.fetch = require("jest-fetch-mock");

  const mockInfo = jest.spyOn(global.console, "info").mockImplementation(
      () => { console.error("mockInfo") }
  );

  await ourModule.functionBeingTested("test");  // ...and wait for the Promise to resolve
  expect(mockInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: Of course - now that you point it out it's obvious. I'm pretty new to async code so it didn't occur to me. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @ScottMartin no problem, glad it helped